# JOIN с временной таблицей

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация-запросов

Есть временная таблица

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT" (
    "POINT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("POINT_ID") ENABLE
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

И есть persistent таблица

```
CREATE TABLE "CONTROL_POINTS_" (
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" NUMBER(1,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_CONTROL_POINTS_" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE 
);
```

Во временной таблице 200 записей, в персистентной 29 000

Делаю запрос

```
SELECT
  cp.status
FROM
  TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT det
  JOIN CONTROL_POINTS_ cp ON (
    det.POINT_ID = cp.ID
  )
```

и ужасаюсь плану

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                          |   200 |  3800 |    18   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |                          |   200 |  3800 |    18   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT |   200 |  2600 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CONTROL_POINTS_          | 29303 |   171K|    16   (7)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("DET"."POINT_ID"="CP"."ID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

Потом меняю в запросе выбираемое поле

```
SELECT
  cp.id
FROM
  TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT det
  JOIN CONTROL_POINTS_ cp ON (
    det.POINT_ID = cp.ID
  )
```

И получаю ожидаемый план

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                          |   200 |  3600 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS      |                          |   200 |  3600 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT |   200 |  2600 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN| PK_CONTROL_POINTS_       |     1 |     5 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("DET"."POINT_ID"="CP"."ID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Кто нибудь может объяснить, что происходит? Откуда берется FULL SCAN? Сам запрос выбирает честные 200 записей

Манипуляции типа

```
SELECT
  cp.STATUS
FROM
  CONTROL_POINTS_ cp
WHERE
  cp.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT det)
```

приводят к еще более удручающим последствиям

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                          |  5860K|    33M|  2820   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|                          |  5860K|    33M|  2820   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT |   200 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   BUFFER SORT        |                          | 29303 |   171K|  2818   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | CONTROL_POINTS_          | 29303 |   171K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update**

Временная таблица ни при чем. С персистентной такой же структуры и такими же данными та же картина

Comment: Почему ужасный план? Оптимизатор считает, что быстрее выбрать все записи и потом объединить через hash join, чем искать в индексе и дёргать из таблицы. 30К записей не так уж и много, всё в памяти поместится.

Comment: @0xdb Да потому, что потом джойнится еще пара таблиц и там вообще дикие значения получаются. До 200К записей доходит

Comment: Собственно, криминального ничего нет. Оптимизатор считает, что так быстрее, почему именно сложно сказать. Но он намекает, что ваши 29 тысяч строк - это 171K. Надо скорее исходить из того, достаточно ли быстро работает запрос для ваших задач. И если не достаточно, то уже можно попробовать оптимизировать хинтами

Comment: От себя могу добавить: даже во втором случае оптимизатор мог отказаться от индекса и более медленного NL и выбрать full scan с быстрым hash join. Всё зависит, сколько он предугадает кол-во строчек в обоих rowset и, следовательно, сколько  примерно IO операций потребуется. В вашем случае - фильтр только с equi inner join и сравнительно небольшим кол-вом строк - то, что выбор падёт на hash join или sorted merge, ожидаемо и даже желательно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба плана абсолютно предсказуемы. во втором случае вам нужно только значение из индекса, поэтому берется индекс.

А в первом случае нужно получать значение из области данных. При этом данных у вас 29000 записей, при средней длине записи около 4х байт. На диске вся таблица занимает 171 Кбайт (что видно в плане). При размере блока на диске в 4к это 43 блока. Получать 43 блока за 200 отдельных обращений по указателям из индекса мягко говоря накладно (Гарантировано будет прочитана вся таблица, причем каждый блок придется разбирать 4 раза). Full scan да еще и с hash join более чем оправдан.

Использование индекса эффективно, когда с его помощью нужно обратиться не более чем к 10% всех блоков таблицы.

Comment: Исходная проблема в том, что в реальном запросе джойнятся еще две таблицы. А из-за FULL SCAN по `CONTROL_POINTS` запускается FULL SCAN по остальным таблицам. В итоге получаю выборку  228K строк с размером  2896K байт. Тоже считать нормальным?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А что вы еще такое джоините к этой таблице и главное по каким полям, если в ней только status и id... И 2 Мб это в общем то не особо много. Время выполнения какое ? И я лишь говорю, чем руководствуется оптимизатор. Если вас не устраивает план, применяйте хинты

Comment: Время выполнения ~0.3-0.5 секунд. Это вместе с фетчем. Джойны только по индексированным полям. Ладно, позицию оптимизатора я понял. Спасибо

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Достаточно подсунуть в запрос `use_nl (control_points)` и посмотреть, станет ли лучше.

Comment: @0xdb `use_nl` побоку. А вот `index` привел запрос в чувство

Answer (score -1):

Использование хинта `index` привел запрос в чувство

```
SELECT  /*+ index(cp PK_CONTROL_POINTS) */
  cp.STATUS
FROM
  TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT det
  JOIN CONTROL_POINTS PARTITION (lic) cp ON (
    det.POINT_ID = cp.ID
  )
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                          |   200 |  4000 |   202   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                       |                          |   200 |  4000 |   202   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                      |                          |   200 |  4000 |   202   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                | TMP_CONTROL_POINT_DETECT |   200 |  2600 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | PK_CONTROL_POINTS        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| CONTROL_POINTS           |     1 |     7 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("DET"."POINT_ID"="CP"."ID")
       filter(TBL$OR$IDX$PART$NUM("CONTROL_POINTS",0,1,0,ROWID)=2)
```